# how to get the coordinates of a draggable marker andorid?

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-markers, huawei-mobile-services, vuedraggable

Good afternoon I am implementing a map, you can enter my position of a marker, but how can I get the new latitude and longitude of the marker when moving to another position

Comment: mMap.cameraPosition.target where mMap is GoogleMap instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is how to obtain the new longitude and latitude of a marker after it is dragged to a new position.

HUAWEI Map Kit provides the **HuaweiMap.OnMarkerDragListener() API** to listen for marker drag events. For details about this API, please visit [HuaweiMap.OnMarkerDragListener](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/onmarkerdraglistener-0000001050150108-V5).

You can override the onMarkerDragStart, onMarkerDrag, and onMarkerDragEnd methods in the API to obtain the marker information under different drag status.

The sample code is as follows:

```
hMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new HuaweiMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        Log.i(TAG, "start drag");
        // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        Log.i(TAG, "drag");
// your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
// your code
        Log.i(TAG, "end drag");
        Log.i(TAG, marker.getPosition().toString());
```