# How to get the new coordinates of draggable marker in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I have the following marker that is added successfully on a Google Map:

```
Marker(
    state = MarkerState(
        position = LatLng(lat, lng)
    ),
    title = "Party",
    snippet = "Come to party.",
    draggable = true
)
```

I set this marker to be draggable and it works, but how to know the new coordinated when the marker is dropped?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done by remembering the marker state you are passing to the `Marker`; for instance, you can write the following code and query the state for the new coordinates or pass that state to where you want to get the updates:

```kotlin
val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = LatLng(lat, lng))
Marker(
    state = markerState
    title = "Party",
    snippet = "Come to party.",
    draggable = true
)
```

That way, on every recomposition, upon dragging the marker, the new position will be in the `markerState`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions but I don't understand, how to get the new coordinates? This my question. Is there a callback for that? [On a regular map, it was very simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726432/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-a-draggable-marker-andorid).

Comment: Well, that's the thing, you don't get new coordinates via a callback, when you are moving the marker, you are simply changing its state, so the `markerState` will be holding the new coordinates! that's the compose way!

Comment: I just tried your solution, but I get [the addition and the deletion of the makers messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920971/how-to-make-remembermarkerstate-work-correctly-in-jetpack-compose). Maybe you can take a look. Thanks. I really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I used LaunchedEffect with key markerState.position and from that coroutine I could get new LatLng.

```
   val markerState = rememberMarkerState(position = LatLng(lat, lng))
   Marker(
       state = markerState
       title = "Party",
       snippet = "Come to party.",
       draggable = true
   )
   LaunchedEffect(key1 = markerState.position) {
       Log.d(TAG, "New coordinates: ${markerState.position}")
   }
```