# How to make rememberMarkerState work correctly in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add and delete markers to/from Google Map. When I'm using the `markerState` which is defined as you can see below:

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    onMapLongClick = { latLng ->
        viewModel.addPlace(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)
    }
) {
    places.forEach { place ->
        val markerState = MarkerState(
            position = LatLng(place.lat, place.lng)
        )

        Marker(
            state = markerState,
            title = "Party",
            snippet = "Come to party.",
            onInfoWindowLongClick = {
                viewModel.deletePlace(place.id)
            },
            draggable = true
        )
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. I can add the delete markers as expected. The problem is that I need to track the marker state, so I changed the declaration of the `markerState` to:

```
val markerState = rememberMarkerState(
    position = LatLng(place.lat, place.lng)
)
```

Once I use this new `markerState` when I want to add a new marker, the marker is added in database but not on the screen and if I want to delete a marker, it deletes any other marker but the one that is selected? Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @RowanGontier No, not yet :( If you find a solution, please add it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to use different key param for each marker?

Comment: @user924 Yes, it behaves the same. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hello, do we have the fix from google map compose team or anything :( 
Facing the same issue, need to rememberMarkerState to have the showInfoWindow work correctly, but by that way, it reused the previous marker and map refresh marker doesn't work